# KVM Default Network Gives Same IP to Different Machines

Tags: networking, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to create VMs using KVM.

I am using libvirt to create the VMs, with following packages

```
bridge-utils libvirt-daemon-system virt-manager virt-viewer qemu-kvm qemu-efi
```

And the command to create vm:

```
virt-install --import --name guest1 \
        --memory 2048 --vcpus 1 --noautoconsole \
        --os-variant ubuntu22.04 --hvm \
        --network network=default \
        --disk=/vm-images/jammy01.img --import

virt-install --import --name guest2 \
        --memory 2048 --vcpus 1 --noautoconsole \
        --os-variant ubuntu22.04 --hvm \
        --network network=default \
        --disk=/vm-images/jammy02.img --import

virt-install --import --name guest3 \
        --memory 2048 --vcpus 1 --noautoconsole \
        --os-variant ubuntu22.04 --hvm \
        --network network=default \
        --disk=/vm-images/jammy03.img --import
```

The network=default is:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>9ea90610-3814-4508-b943-3e53aa5d3404</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:6a:55:17'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

And netplan yaml in each machines:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

However, all the machines are having same IP even I'm using dhcp4.

Simply, I checked it with `virsh net-dhcp-leases default`, and it is

```
 Expiry Time           MAC address         Protocol   IP address           Hostname   Client ID or DUID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2023-02-22 12:07:14   00:50:52:a7:d7:92   ipv4       192.168.122.241/24   ubuntu     ff:5d:e2:6c:15:00:02:00:00:ab:11:33:33:f1:46:a3:8b:cb:28
```

Only one ip is assigned.
As the machines are provisioned, only MAC address are changed.

How can I solve this problem?

I expected, each machines will have own IP address, something like:

```
 Expiry Time           MAC address         Protocol   IP address           Hostname   Client ID or DUID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2023-02-22 12:07:14   00:50:52:a7:d7:92   ipv4       192.168.122.241/24   ubuntu     ff:5d:e2:6c:15:00:02:00:00:ab:11:33:33:f1:46:a3:8b:cb:28
 2023-02-22 12:07:14   00:50:52:b7:a7:22   ipv4       192.168.122.151/24   ubuntu     ff:5d:e2:6c:15:00:02:00:00:ab:11:33:33:f1:46:a3:8b:cb:28
 2023-02-22 12:07:14   00:50:52:17:5b:ef   ipv4       192.168.122.199/24   ubuntu     ff:5d:e2:6c:15:00:02:00:00:ab:11:33:33:f1:46:a3:8b:cb:28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was dhcp identifier was set into `Machine Id` as default.

As I created machine by template, I have to change the machine id on `/etc/machine-id` or explicitly declare the `dhcp-indeitifer` that I will use MAC address as the identifier.

The last one, explicitly set MAC address as `dhcp-identifier`, you could set it on `/etc/netplan/NETWORK.yaml` ->

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac # This is the key of this problem.
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the IP address explicitly. Example:

```
daniel@kafka2:~$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.122.156/24
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.122.1
      match:
        macaddress: 52:54:00:05:69:b2
      set-name: enp1s0
```

After that apply changes with the netplan command and check if the IP address has changed:

```
root@kafka2:~# netplan apply
root@kafka2:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:05:69:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.155/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe05:69b2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```